# SSL on Tomcat ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I need to configure a Java Angular application to use SSL.

This is how I'm doing.

Generated the .jks using this command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myservername -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore myservername.jks -dname "CN=myservername, O=MyOrg, L=, ST=, C=" && keytool -certreq -alias myservername -file myservername.csr -keystore myservername.jks
```

It generated a myservername.csr file and a myservername.jks file.

Then, I ran this command

`keytool -list -keystore myservername.jks`

and got this result:

```
myservername, Oct 20, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxxxxxxx
```

Then I sent the myservername.csr file to the certificate authority and they sent me back this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I pasted that into a myservername.cer file.

I double click the myservername.cer and went to certificate path tab and I see this:
rootcertname > intermediatecertname > myservername

myservername is the alias I choose in the first command above.

Then I clicked rootcertname > view certificate > details > copy to file > next > Base 64 encoded x.509 (cer)

It generated rootcertname.cer

Then I clicked intermediatecertname > view certificate > details > copy to file > next > Base 64 encoded x.509 (cer)

It generated intermediatecertname.cer

Then I imported both certificates to the keystore like this:

```
keytool -keystore myservername.jks -import -alias intermediate -trustcacerts -file intermediatecertname.cer
keytool -keystore myservername.jks -import -alias root -trustcacerts -file rootcertname.cer
```

Then I ran this command again to list the certificates in the keystore:

```
keytool -list -keystore myservername.jks
```

and got this result:

```
intermediate, Oct 23, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxxx
root, Oct 23, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxx
myservername, Oct 20, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxxx
```

So it has the privatekey (generated in the first command above) plus the root and intermediate certificates from the Certification Authority.

Copied myservername.jks to Tomcat \conf folder.

And configured Tomcat server.xml connector as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="conf\myservername.jks"
           keystorePass="mypass"
           keystoreType="JKS" />
```

But when I access the application on the browser using https I the following error message:

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

It is not a network issue because if I configure server.xml to access it again using http (instead of https), the application opens normally.

Comment: Your steps after signing are not correct. You should have imported the entire signed certificate chain under the alias of the private key entry. At present you don't have a signed certificate at all, just the original self-signed one. But that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is **not a network issue** because if I configure server.xml to access it again using http (instead of https), the application opens normally.

HTTP and HTTPS use different default ports. HTTP is using port 80, HTTPS port 443. What you describe sounds like a firewall allowing access to port 80 but dropping attempts to access port 443.

While nothing is known about your network environment there are cloud environments which by default block almost anything, including port 443. To allow access one need to actively change the firewall settings to allow access. Note that there might be also multiple firewalls involved in this, like a firewall on the system itself but also firewalls somewhere between the client and server system.

Comment: Good catch. When I changed to port 443 it connected. But still getting an error Not secure - Certificate is not valid. And in the Issued By field I see the issuer name is myservername. It should be the Certification Authority. So there's also something wrong in the ssl installation.

Comment: @jkfe: your original question was answered. What you ask now is a different problem and should be asked in a new question.

Comment: Ok then. Answered accepted. Thanks.